# How to add items of generic type to list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Should be relativly simple but I cant figure it out, i have the following:

```
  public static List<T> GetList <T>(dynamic data)
    {
        var lst = new List<T>();

        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            lst.Add(new T { Value = d.Id.ToString(), Text = d.Name };);
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

errror:

[image]

Comment: Why not use interfaces?

Comment: you have no constraints on `T`.  The compiler doesn't know that `T` has a `Value` or `Text` property.

Comment: You constrained your type to T but provided no additional constraints on that type. The compiler cannot know there exists a property Value or Text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You constrained your type to T but provided no additional constraints on that type. The compiler cannot know there exists a property Value or Text. You could use an interface and then constrain on that type. The type you pass in when you call the method must also implement that interface.

```
public interface ITextValue{
   string Text {get;set;}
   string Value {get;set;}
}
```

And then the code with the added constraint

```
public static List<T> GetList <T>(dynamic data) where T : ITextValue, new()
{
    var lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        lst.Add(new T { Value = d.Id.ToString(), Text = d.Name });
    }

    return lst;
}
```

---

Here is a good link on all of the available constraints and syntax for those constraints that you can apply to generic type parameters. [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). And along with what @juan pointed out the `new()` constraint specifies that the type you use must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: One thing I would like to add that I think @Igor forgot to mention is the new() constraint. It tells the compiler that T has a public parameterless constructor (which is what lets you do new T{}).

Comment: One more thing. If possible, I would avoid using dynamic as it skips compile time checking. You could instead have the classes that you pass to this method implement the interface that @Igor described.

Comment: I just started reading the same guide. Thanks for pointing it out though. 
@Juan thx for the extra pointers. Dynamic is used since time is limited, refactoring will probably be done at a point.

Comment: You remind me of something I read a long time ago. It went something along the lines of "If you don't have time to do it the right way now, what makes you think you will have time to fix it later"... LOL. I am glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

With C# generics you are only allowed to perform those operations on a instance of a generic type argument that are known to the compiler to exist in any type that fits the generic type constraints as specified by the respective generic type or generic method. In other words, in your specific case the compiler has two problems.

First, you try to construct an instance of T, though not every type can be constructed like that (e.g. delegates cannot). Moreover, not every **constructible** type is **default-constructible** (in other words has a default constructor). To be able to construct an instance of type T like that, you need to require T to have a default constructor be applying the **new()** constraint on T.

Second, to be able to initialize properties **Value** and **Text** on the newly-constructed instance of T you need to be sure that type T specifies such properties and these properties are **public** and **settable**, which is typically done through enforcing T to implement a certain interface.

Here is a little example of what you would probably want to do in code.

```
interface IHasStringValueAndText {
    String Value { get; set; }
    String Text { get; set; }
}

public static List<T> GetList<T>(dynamic data) where T : IHasStringValueAndText, new() {
    var lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (var d in data) {
        lst.Add(new T { Value = d.Id.ToString(), Text = d.Name });
    }

    return lst;
}
```

Please note, that if you're don't really need the **class** constraint for your particular case to work, but it might be useful in your further work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain to a class that contains Value and Text as properties or it won't be able to find those properties. For instance:

Where TypeName is the type that contains Value and Text.

```
  public static List<T> GetList <T>(dynamic data) where T : TypeName, new()
  {
    var lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        lst.Add(new T { Value = d.Id.ToString(), Text = d.Name };);
    }

    return lst;
  }
```

Comment: This won't work. It will still blow up because the compiler doesn't know that T has properties Value and Text or what type they are.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that and added a note